# Redis backed Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I am looking for something where I can keep an entire Rails based Model stored in Redis. There is Redis Objects that is found here https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects but that only works when your model is already backed by something like ActiveRecord and it requires a unique id generator. I don't wish to make an ActiveRecord backed model, as I want to persist everything directly into memory and not into the database.

Is there a drop in tool that I can use right now that'll let me do things like:

`RedisBackedModel.find_by_name('foo')`

and it'll retrieve me the RedisBackedModel from Redis?

Answer (score 7):

I've used [Ohm](https://github.com/soveran/ohm) before for storing searches that expire after a couple hours; it's pretty nice.  I think DataMapper also has a [redis adapter](https://github.com/whoahbot/dm-redis-adapter), although I've never used it.  Here's some Ohm code for what I think you're after:

```
class RedisBackedModel < Ohm::Model
  attribute :name
  index :name
end

rbm = RedisBackedModel.create :name => "foo"
rbm.id # => 1

# Search by name:
RedisBackedModel.find(:name => "foo")

# Search by id (like AR-style model.get(id)):
RedisBackedModel[1]
```

Comment: Did you used OHM with rails?

Comment: They are complaining "Unfortunately we don't use ohm with rails at all (and never plan to)." https://github.com/soveran/ohm/issues/26

Comment: @PravinMishra Yes, I used it on a project a couple years ago when Rails 3.0 had just come out. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Modis](https://github.com/rpush/modis) does exactly this.